# Pick off individual values in Nested json

Tags: php, json

Give the supplied JSON I want to extract the latitude and longitude coordinates only.

```
"vectorQuery": {
    "layers": {
        "50772": {
            "crs": {
                "type": "name",
                "properties": {
                    "name": "EPSG:4326"
                }
            },
            "field_names": ["id", "appellation", "affected_surveys", "parcel_intent", "topology_type", "statutory_actions", "land_district", "titles", "survey_area", "calc_area"],
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": [{
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "MultiPolygon",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [
                                [174.8592712667, -36.9675741167],
                                [174.8593271167, -36.9673525333],
                                [174.8593513167, -36.9672686333],
                                [174.8592025167, -36.9671776333],
                                [174.8591615833, -36.9672144833],
                                [174.8588608833, -36.9674851833],
                                [174.8592451667, -36.9678935833],
                                [174.8592699833, -36.9679199],
                                [174.8594188, -36.9680780333],
                                [174.8597915667, -36.9678483167],
                                [174.85991985, -36.9677692333],
                                [174.8599389, -36.96770445],
                                [174.8596869333, -36.9676552667],
                                [174.8596362667, -36.9676453833],
                                [174.8592712667, -36.9675741167]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                "distance": 0,
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "id": 5073537,
                    "appellation": "Lot 2 DP 64503",
                    "affected_surveys": "DP 64503",
                    "parcel_intent": "DCDB",
                    "topology_type": "Primary",
                    "statutory_actions": null,
                    "land_district": "North Auckland",
                    "titles": "NA20A/1419",
                    "survey_area": 3688.0,
                    "calc_area": 3686.0
                },
                "id": 995125
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

}

I actually just want to get the coordinates. I can pick these of these by ...

```
    print_r($arr['vectorQuery']['layers']['50772']['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][0][0]);
```

The issue being that the key 50772 can change each request. Is there a method of traversing directly to the coordinates?

Comment: Will there only ever be one property in the `layers` object? Or do you need to iterate through multiple?

Comment: There will only ever be one `layer`

Comment: You can find the first key using - `$key = key($arr['vectorQuery']['layers']);`